# plotting MNIST samples

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science, mnist

I'm trying to plot 10 samples from the MNIST dataset. One of each digit. Here's the code:

```
import sklearn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets

mnist = datasets.fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
y = mnist.target
X = mnist.data

for i in range(10):
    im_idx = np.argwhere(y == i)[0]
    print(im_idx)
    plottable_image = np.reshape(X[im_idx], (28, 28))
    plt.imshow(plottable_image, cmap='gray_r')
    plt.subplot(2, 5, i + 1)

plt.plot()
```

For some reason, the zero digit is being skipped in the plot.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I got it. The problem was that you were defining the subplot after plotting `imshow`. So your first subplot was overwritten by the second one. To make your code work, just swap the order of your two commands as following. Also, I don't see why you are using `plt.plot()` at the end.

```
plt.subplot(2, 5, i + 1) # <-- You have put this command after imshow 
plt.imshow(plottable_image, cmap='gray_r')
```

Here is another alternate for your knowledge:

```
fig = plt.figure()

for i in range(10):
    im_idx = np.argwhere(y == i)[0]
    plottable_image = np.reshape(X[im_idx], (28, 28))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 5, i+1)
    ax.imshow(plottable_image, cmap='gray_r')
```

You can also further shorten Scott's code (posted below) by using the following:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,5)
for i, ax in enumerate(ax.flatten()):
    im_idx = np.argwhere(y == i)[0]
    plottable_image = np.reshape(X[im_idx], (28, 28))
    ax.imshow(plottable_image, cmap='gray_r')
```

[image]

Comment: Looking for  a reason why OP code did work?  +1 on your solution.

Comment: @ScottBoston: Found the problem

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
import sklearn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets

mnist = datasets.fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
y = mnist.target
X = mnist.data

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,5)
ax = ax.flatten()
for i in range(10):
    im_idx = np.argwhere(y == i)[0]
    print(im_idx)
    plottable_image = np.reshape(X[im_idx], (28, 28))
    ax[i].imshow(plottable_image, cmap='gray_r')
```

Output:

[image]